# accessing unspecified fields from JodaTime DateTime objects

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have a JodaTime DateTime object parsed by `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()` from a string that may have one or more unspecified fields, such as day in the case of "2012-05", or year in the case of "T11:55". However, it seems that these fields are always populated with default values from the Unix epoch.

Is there any way to know which fields were actually unspecified in the input string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to find out what was or was not parsed when using `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()`. One option would be to try different parsers manually - ie. try with a strict one (date and full time), then drop the millis, then drop the seconds and so on until one of them passes. Painful, but do-able.

JSR-310 is planned to handle this differently, by separating parsing from object construction.

Answer (score 0):

If you have pieces of time information (other then time zone)missing, then you don't have a valid ISO 8601 format.  I'm somewhat surprised Joda Time doesn't throw an error, and not surprised you can't figure out what was missing.

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch04_05.htm

Comment: Thanks Jim. I think that document is only valid for the W3C's "subset of the ISO 8601 standard".

I think the full ISO 8601 specification does support the partial forms I am trying to parse.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates): "The standard also allows for calendar dates to be written with reduced precision. For example, one may write "1981-04" to mean "1981 April", and one may simply write "1981" to refer to that year or "19" to refer to the century from 1900 to 1999 inclusive."